Problem with displaying the object. Django
I want display post in my group(separate posts for each group). I separated posts in main page successfully (before when i created post in group form post display in mainpage). The post is assigned to group in admin site and DB I can create this but i cant display. I don't have error page working.
<a href="{% url 'group_post' group.pk %}" class="submit-style">Dodaj post</a>
            {% for post in post_list %}

class PostGroupListView(ListView):

    model = Post
    template_name = 'rooms/group_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'post_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        group_id = self.kwargs['group_id']
        return Post.objects.filter(group_id=group_id)

class PostGroupCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

    model = Post
    fields = ['content', 'image']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        group_id = self.kwargs.get('group_id')
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        group = get_object_or_404(Group, id=group_id)
        form.instance.group = group
        return super().form_valid(form)

class GroupPostDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'group_post'

def some_view(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_id)
    return render(request, 'group_detail.html', {'post': post})

Post Display in group
class GroupDetailView(DetailView):

    model = Group
    context_object_name = 'group'
    template_name = 'rooms/group_detail.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'group_id'

   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = AddGroupMemberForm(group_id=self.object.id)
        context['members'] = GroupMembers.objects.filter(group=self.object) #Download all members
        context['post'] = Post.objects.filter(group=self.object)
        return context


context['post_list'] = Post.objects.filter(group=self.object)
